# Java Regular Expression giving a different result with variable input and string input

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to convert a wildcard-enabled url to a Regular Expression (`Pattern`), so I can use it later to match against wildcarded url.

Then I discovered that despite having the same string value, using a variable input (`String regex = 'str'`) produces a different result from a direct string input `"regex str"`.

I cannot find this behavior on the official document.

```
String destination = "*.example.com";
String regex = destination.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\\\\\.");
regex = regex.replaceAll("\\*", "\\.\\*");
System.out.println(regex);                             //this gives ".*\\.example\\.com"

System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "office.example.com"));         //false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(".*\\.example\\.com", "office.example.com"));  //true
```

Comment: What is `regex` initially? Also, `destination..replaceAll` does not compile. EDIT: Post was updated

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart sorry for the typos, I updated the code above

Comment: Please see the help about providing a MCVE (minimum complete verifiable example). It will vastly increase the possibility that someone will provide the help you're seeking.

Comment: [The strings are different](https://tio.run/##jVLNb8IgFL/3r3jjIm03uvM6t3jfkiUe5w6s0hZHPwa0cVH/dvcqarQ2Ri7A4/f1gAVv@cNi/rOVRV1pCwvcs8ZKxbTIxJIFseclihsD71yWK69uvpVMwFhucWorOYcCD@jUallmn1/AdWZ8WG1dAebCWFkiuCphDCRgYsmLWgmWVAWJvT1q54XnJ2j0rxVPxEQpSmYzRu4BJzcY8WPvwHE5z9GBQ7NuhdDpn7GiYFVjWY1@VpV0x/JjuDaiyObSQCZbYYCwAAX36XHV5feGlD@4tUKXrOA2yYVxThinSlOZiLP@/ZMAUZRyZcQtikNRrhhgG7oRhwfhiW246t5iQCUe7Ig4qgHxi1TzCiR0l@721Emi1zD7TZSZzc3TkaZ2BeqHBFq82NDxj@VOJ600RTpIDPoY4/QM51yshSH@M6@7O5lS@TLuyazXjpHkXE8slf7dAXGs@NDPS3sczNIZCHyZS@wIRni@GWoa6wMt9BL2e@h5j2/JewG5JbC32Wz/AQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need two '\' because it's in string variable definition. The statement regex= ".*\\.example\\.com", the actually value of regex is ".*\.example\.com" after the statement executed. So you can change to destination.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\.") to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of escapes in play here: string and regex. It's easy to lose track of what's what. The use of `replaceAll` makes things even harder.

I think you want:

```
String destination = "*.example.com";
String regex = destination.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*");

System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "office.example.com"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(".*\\.example\\.com", "office.example.com"));
```